# Can't "set next statement" when debugging Unity game

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine

I'm using Visual Studio to debug a Unity game. When it stops at a breakpoint, I'd like to change the next line to be executed.

I want to do this by dragging the arrow icon in the left gutter, but it doesn't work.

[image: bug demonstration]

How do I set the next statement when debugging a Unity game?

Comment: I didn't even know what you can move it. What does this *moving*? Maybe it's a debugger feature Unity doesn't support?

Comment: Drag the execution line? What are you trying to do?

Comment: just guessing here: you're trying to change the next statement to be executed, and that statement uses two vars `cos` and `sin`, and you're trying to jump over the place where they are put on the stack, which doesn't sound good. did you try to change execution line in other cases? Usually I use right-click -> set next statement, didn't know you can drag it by mouse

Comment: **It's not a bug...** The feature of dragging current execution marker is not available in Unity.

Comment: Right-click on the line where you want to move the execution point and see if there is an option in context-menu "Set next statement", if it is there and greyed out the feature is not available

Comment: Where do you **want to drag the instruction pointer**?

Comment: Yes i wanted to use command "set next statement" but thats not available in unity, im so dissapointed..

Comment: I found the screenshot was taken from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1350283/cant-change-debugger-execution-line-while-debug.html)

Comment: I don't think the downvotes are justified; I've updated the title to something less ... ambiguous, I guess. I've also spruced up the text.

Comment: I clicked on the question to see wtf the question meant, and while I had to read the comments to understand (as it is not a feature I knew that VS had, nor does now knowing that help, as it isn't supported in Unity) it is not a *bad question.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is (currently) not supported while executing code running in the unity engine (which uses unityvs as a bridge).

For a list of supported features please see this page : http://unityvs.com/features/